# formatting ggplot scales with s3 method and objects attributes

Tags: r, ggplot2, formatting

I have two custom classes that have different types of constructors and different types of formatting methods, one class relying on the attributes of the object.

```
as.test_1 <- function(x, test_attribute, ...) {
  attributes(x) <- list("test_attribute" = test_attribute)
  x <-
    structure(x, class = c("test_1", setdiff(class(x), "test_1")))
  return(x)
}

format.test_1  <- function(x, ...) {
  paste0(x, attributes(x)$test_attribute)
}

print.test_1 <- function(x, ...) {
  cat(format(x, ...), "\n")
}

as.test_2 <- function(x, test_attribute, ...) {
  x <-
    structure(x, class = c("test_2", setdiff(class(x), "test_2")))
  return(x)
}

format.test_2  <- function(x, ...) {
  paste0(x, "test")
}

print.test_2 <- function(x, ...) {
  cat(format(x, ...), "\n")
}
```

Now I want to to plot some data that contains these classes:

```
library(data.table)

data_1 <-
  data.table(a = as.test_1(c(1, 2, 3, 4), test_attribute = "test"),
             b = as.factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d")))
data_2 <-
  data.table(a = as.test_2(c(1, 2, 3, 4), test_attribute = "test"),
             b = as.factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d")))
```

Also I want to use the format method to format the y-axis. This is my first try, which works for the test_2 class that does not rely on the attributes of the variable for formatting:

```
library(ggplot2)
plot_data <- function(data) {
  g <- ggplot(data, aes(x = b, y = a))
  g <- g +  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  expand <- c(0, 0)
  attributes(expand) <- attributes(data$a)
  limits <- c(0, 4)
  attributes(limits) <- attributes(data$a)
  g <- g + scale_y_continuous(
    expand = expand,
    limits = limits,
    oob = scales::squish,
    labels = getS3method(f = "format", class = class(data$a)[[1]])
  )
  return(print(g))
}
```

However for the test_1 class it seems like the attributes get lost somewhere in the call of scale_y_continuous.

```
plot_data(data_1)
```

[image]

```
plot_data(data_2)
```

[image]

Does someone know how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: You don't call any `geom_*` in your plot, that may be the reason.

Comment: @Jet thank you for your suggestion. I edited my question but adding the geom_bar call does not seem to affect the formatting of the y axis labels.

Comment: I think it is very difficult to get any of the data.frame columns to retain their attributes throughout the data processing within ggplot. I've only seen this implemented once, by the ggperiodic package and I think that solution relied on the sticky package. So that are my two cents on where to look for answers.